# iptables question for port forwarding

Tags: linux, port, iptables

I have a web server running on my server on port 7000. I want it to be accessible on port 80. I've read that this could be easily done with iptables port forwarding.
What would the correct command would be to achieve that?

E

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something along the lines of this:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 7000
```